# Groupped grid collapse groups on group click

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, grouping, sencha-architect

I have a groupped grid. All the items are collapsed at the start. I want to achieve the functionallity that only one group can be expanded at once. My idea was the following: On group click collapse all the groups and expand the clicked group again. But I am stuck at the first part (collapsing all the groups). I get the following error in browser console:

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onRefresh' of undefined .... Grouping.js
```

Code:

```
 onGroupingGroupclick()view, node, group, eOpts){
       view.collapseAll(); //error
    }
```

If my approach is not ok for some reason I would kindly ask for any alternatives...

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: SenchaArchitect 3.0 and ExtJs 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view` variable in your `groupclick` event listener contain instance of `Ext.view.Table`. But you have to call `collapseAll()` method on instance of `Ext.grid.feature.Grouping` feature which you use in your grid for grouping.

So your grid config should be like this:

```
features: [{
    ftype:'grouping',
    startCollapsed: true       
}],    
listeners: {
    groupclick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {

        view.features[0].collapseAll();
        view.features[0].expand(group);
    }
}
```

See live example in this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2f8

Comment: I had to bind your code to "groupexpand" event because the "gropuclick" would not fire. Now I get view.features is undefined

Comment: I know and thanks for the help. But not my groupclick event doesn't fire and I am stuck there.

Comment: Which subversion of ExtJs 4.2 are you using? Do you have listener for `gropuclick` event defined on `grid` component?

Comment: I have it defined under my grouping feature. I am using Ext JS 4.2.x

Comment: You have to defined listener on `grid` (as i have it in the fiddle). The `groupclick` event is fired by grid, not by grouping feature.

Comment: But if I look under grid I cannot add it. I am doing this in architect

Comment: I have added the function manually. Wasn't aware that you could do that! Now it is working. Thank you!